# Посчитать префиксные суммы с конца. Python

Tags: python

Решаю [задачу](https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=111801).
Есть массив префиксных сумм [0,2,5,10,13] (для чисел 2,3,5,3 соответственно). Мне нужно посчитать сумму последних k элементов. Допустим k = 2. Значит с конца массива нужно посчитать (13 - 10) + (10-5) = 8. Не могу реализовать это в коде, как сделать?
Вот мой код:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
rez = []#ответы
pref = [0]#суммы
for i in range(n):
    b = input()
    if b[0] == "-":#если просят удалить
        rez.append(a.pop())
    elif b[0] == "+":#если просят добавить
        a.append(int(b[1:]))
        pref.append(pref[-1]+int(b[1:]))
    elif b[0] == "?":#если просят вывести сумму последних k эдементов
        k = int(b[1:])
        #print(a)
        rez.append(sum(a[-k:]))

for i in rez:#выводим ответы
    print(i)
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо показать код.

Comment: Подумайте над задачей хорошенько, она решается за одно вычитание, а не за `k` вычитаний, как у вас.

Comment: Я вреде понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Нужно от pref[-1] - pref[-(k+1)], но тогда я не могу правильно обновить суммы, и последние ответы получаются не правильными.

Comment: Какие последние ответы?

Comment: Последние ответы суммы последних k элементов

Comment: @Maksim Формула `pref[-1] - pref[-(k+1)],` правильная. Что не так-то? При удалении пациент не забыли удалить также последний pref?

Comment: Спасибо, задачу решил. Я неправильно удалял pref. Я от каждого по счёту prefa отнимал удаляемый элемент из масива a

Answer (score 3):

Вам наверняка предложат "ванильное" решение, но мне это не интересно, поэтому вот вам с `numpy`, например:

```
import numpy as np

sums = [0,2,5,10,13] # ваши суммы
k = 2 # ваше k

res = sum(np.diff(sums,1)[-k:])
print(res)
# 8
```

Comment: `res = np.diff(sums[-k-1:]).sum()` ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот пусть будет без `Numpy`, на основании кода @strawdog и @MaxU:

```
sums = [0,2,5,10,13] # ваши суммы
k = 2 # ваше k

res = sum([y - x for x, y in zip(sums[-k-1:], sums[-k:])])
print(res)
# 8
```

Хотя да, прав @extrn, на самом деле суммы тут вообще не нужны, нужно просто два элемента вычесть, только сообразить какие.